# Return a value in Swift

Tags: swift2

I want to call a function within another class . But they do not return dictionary in swift. How to solve this?

In my `ViewController`

```
var dict = NSDictionary()
dict = temp.GetStation(myUrl)
```

In my class

```
func GetStation(url : String) -> NSDictionary {

    let dicts = NSDictionary()
    getResonse(url, completionhandler: { (dict) -> NSDictionary in
    //  print(dict)

        return dict                    
    })

    return dicts;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code.**

```
func GetStation(url : String, completionHandler: (stationDictionary: NSDictionary) -> NSDictionary ) {

        getResonse(url, completionhandler: { (dict) -> NSDictionary in
            //  print(dict)

            completionHandler(stationDictionary: dict)
        })

   }
```

and use it like,

```
var dict = NSDictionary()
temp.GetStation("your url") { (stationDictionary) -> NSDictionary in
            dict = stationDictionary;
            print("your dictionary := \(stationDictionary)")
        }
```

We have added `completionHandler` instead of `return value`, because in function `GetStation` you are calling function `getResonse` which is asychronous, may be calling webservice.

So the response of `GetStation` depends on the response of `getResonse`.

Comment: completionHandler(stationDictionary: dict)  got error on this line cannot convert value of type() to closure type Nsdictionary

Comment: Please check the edited answer, thanks

Comment: No it is not working

Comment: now check code for "and use it like,"  section